# Spring error in Restful webservice calling

Tags: java, web-services, spring

When I am trying to access rezgo sample api using restful webservice I am getting exception. I want to get convert this response in sample object

```
package com.mycompany.hr.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
          acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
          //ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/spring-rest-provider/krams/person/{id}", HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class, id);
          Map<String,String> urlParam=new HashMap<String,String>();
          urlParam.put("key","2D8-F3V0-X7C0-C6I");
          urlParam.put("transcode", "p103");
          urlParam.put("i", "p103");
          urlParam.put("t", "tag");
          urlParam.put("q", "nature");

          RestTemplate wsTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         ResponseEntity<TourList> tl=( wsTemplate).getForEntity("http://xml.rezgo.com/xml?key=2D8-F3V0-X7C0-C6I&transcode=p103&i=search_items&t=tag&q=nature",TourList.class,Collections.singleton(urlParam));

    }

}
```

this is my code I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.<init>(UriComponents.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.<init>(UriTemplate.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpUrlTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:229)
    at com.mycompany.hr.client.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Appears like a mismatch in the versions of spring jars being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap` was added in Spring 3.1 but does not appear in earlier versions.  Sounds like you are building your application using spring-core 3.1, but your runtime environment is using an earlier version.

Perhaps you upgraded Spring recently and have a stale lib directory somewhere that includes multiple versions of spring-core?  In my experience Java always seems to pick the wrong one (older) and I get errors like these.  Make sure you do not have spring-core 3.0 or earlier anywhere in your environment.